# sending parameters from a server written in server to another java runtime library

Tags: java, parameters, nanohttpd

I'm running NanoHTTPD as a server , reading the inputs from client side.

These parameters taken from the user are to be passed to another java program which actually manipulates that data and sends back to the java server.

So, is there any way to send these parameters from this server to another Java program ,which is actually a part of runtime library of another new language called system j which is under development.

Answer (score 0):

The approach I would recommend is to front-end your Java program with another listener like NanoHTTPD or a servlet container like Grizzly, Tomcat, JBoss, Glassfish or Jetty.  You could use a framework like Jersey to simplify the REST communications between the two services.

Other alternatives exist, such as hacking together your own protocols using [Sockets](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/) or executing a Process and passing your parameters as you would to any other executable.